# Python MySQLdb using %S multiple times in one line

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

```
    Date = self.Date.selectedDate()
    Date = QDate.toPyDate(Date)

    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="Benjamin217", db="Auski")
    c = db.cursor()

    vins = "SELECT Sum(ChildrenNum) FROM OrderDetails WHERE CheckInDate <= '%s' AND CheckOutDate > '%s'"

    vins2 = "SELECT Sum(AdultNum) FROM OrderDetails WHERE CheckInDate <= '%s' AND CheckOutDate > '%s'"

    c.execute(vins, [Date], [Date])
    ChildrenNum = c.fetchone()[0]
    c.execute(vins2, [Date], [Date])
    AdultNum = c.fetchone()[0]
    print(ChildrenNum + AdultNum)
    c.close()
    db.close()
```

Gives the Error:

```
c.execute(vins, [Date], [Date])
```

TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Im pretty much trying to select all the entries where my inputed date lies between. im wondering if anyone has a cleaner way to do this that preferably works. Because i haven't been able to find a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the values as separate one-item lists, rather than as a single list. This would work:

```
c.execute(vins, [Date, Date])
```